# Rails many to many associations and has_many, through:

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created my models a week ago, but I didn't know many things that I know now so it is time to create it from scratch.

What I want to accomplish is to create:

1. Lab model that can have many offers
2. Offer model that can have many labs.

   ```
   #MIGRATION FILES BELOW:
   class CreateLabs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
     def change
       create_table :labs do |t|
         t.string :name
         ...

         t.timestamps
       end
     end
   end

   class CreateOffers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
     def change
       create_table :offers do |t|
         t.string :name
         ...

         t.timestamps
       end
     end
   end

   # Join table:
   class CreateLabChain < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
     def change
       create_table :lab_chain do |t|
         t.references :lab, foreign_key: true
         t.references :offer, foreign_key: true
         t.timestamps
       end
     end
   end
   ```

And here is how the model files look like:

```
class Lab < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :offers, through: :lab_chain
    has_many :lab_chains
end

class Offer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :labs, through: :lab_chain
  has_many :lab_chains
end

class LabChain < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :lab
    belongs_to :offer
end
```

I just want to know if I wrote it all correctly as I am not sure about all those tutorials I have watched and read.

Bonus question is what if I want my Offer to have many sections, and section to have many offer_items? Should I just add:

to Offer:

```
has_many :sections
has_many :offer_items, through: :section
```

and then to Section:

```
has_many :offer_items
belongs_to :offer
```

and the to OfferItem:

```
belongs_to :section
```

?
As I mentioned before, I volunteered as a guy that would make a website for our school project as I was the only one that had something to do with code (different language). It is harder than I thought.

**EDIT**

How would I also correctly add an self join in Section, so a section can have a subsection and so on?

**Self joins addded to Section model**

```
has_many :child_sections, class_name: "Section", foreign_key: "section_id"
belongs_to :parent_section, class_name: "Section"
```

**Added to migration file**

```
t.references :parent_section, foreign_key: "section_id"
```

Answer (score 1):

That does look like a correct many to many association.  You second also looks correct.

As an aside, it helps to draw a diagram of any database with more than 3 tables and if you plan on doing this as a job, it's well worth it to really grasp the whole table relationships fully as it's core to writing good model code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! What if I want to add a self join to a section model? So a section can have subsection? Edit with code included

Comment: @Ancinek You don't need a Subsection model/table, specially if you want to do self join. Your sections table should have a parent_id column. A category is a subcategory when it has a parent_id value pointing to another category record. Categories with a NULL parent_id are the top level categories. So you can have a code such as   has_many :sub_section, class_name: "Section", foreign_key: :parent_id then you should create a migration to add the parent_id column to the sections table.